# No data being passed through NSUserDefaults

Tags: swift, nsuserdefaults

I have been having a strange issue with NSUserDefaults. I am simply trying to save a string however it keeps returning blank.

When I close the app and reopen it and load the string from NSUserDefaults, no matter what I have inputted it doesn't display anything in the label I am using. I know that the string contains the correct data before it goes through NSUserDefaults as I have tried putting it in a println.

Here is my code that is relevant to the string:

```
    formattedNumberTotal = formatter.stringFromNumber(currencyDouble)
    println(formattedNumberTotal)
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(formattedNumberTotal, forKey: "userInitialBudget")

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        totalBudgetDisplay.text = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("userInitialBudget")
}
```

I have other variables that I am handing exactly the same way and they work absolutely fine. So I can't see where the problem is occurring.

Comment: What is the type of `formattedNumberTotal`? `NSUserDefaults` only works wit a limited number of types: `NSData`, `NSString`, `NSNumber`, `NSDate`, `NSArray`, `NSDictionary`  and combinations of these. Not allowed are Swift `String`, `Array` or `Dictionary`. Note that this is a very popular question a little searching would have provided the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the response. It's a String so I see no reason why it isn't working. Yeah, I should have done a quick search before asking.

Comment: Ah! I had no idea Swift Strings were not allowed. I'll give it a try as an NSString then.

Comment: You might also consider filing a bug report with Apple requesting Swift datatype support. Although most usage of `NSUserDefaults` should be using another method, it is not a database or general persistent store.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Changing it to an NSString fixed the issue. Yeah, I have read that Core Data or NSCoding etc... are the correct way to save data but as I am new to Swift/Xcode I want to keep things simple for my first test app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you save a `String` using `setObject()` then when you retrieve it use `objectForKey()`.
I was able to save `Swift`'s `String` in `NSUserDefaults`

This works fine using Xcode6 beta6:

```
func saveValue(value: AnyObject, forKey: String) {
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(value, forKey: forKey);
}

func getValue(#key: String) -> AnyObject? {
    return NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey(key);
}
```

Comment: Do you need to `synchronise` the userDefaults in the `saveValue` method?

Comment: No. But you can do it if it's necessary.